# Design a table to store different values for single entity?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

I am designing a database where I have a doubt. My requirement is to store the subject score for each student. I can achieve in two ways like below.

> 1. student_id and each subject as column and store one record for each student.
> 2. student_id,subject_name,score as columns and store one record per subject.

I need help in understanding the pros and cons of each implementation type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or table for `Students`:

```
StudentID - primary key
StudentName
etc.
```

and one for `Subjects`:

```
SubjectID - primary key
SubjectName
etc.
```

and one for `Scores`:

```
SubjectID 
StudentID
Score
etc. (might be you want date here)
PrimaryKey (SubjectID, StudentID, SemesterID?)
```

Think about the last table - it will combine student and subject details given a score for each entity but you may need to add some date here, or exam ID or something else as one student may have score for same subject during the years (for example on math).

Comment: Thanks much. I had a similar thought but then my worry was we will be ending up with multiple rows for a single set of records. Isn't that a costly operation?

Comment: @Arockia - the opposite - this is more clear design. It will be better to check `Database normalization` rules, but let's think without knowing the theory. If we stuck with `student_id,subject_name,score` fir example, you will have duplicate `subject names` strings - it will take less space if you replace such strings with number as numbers take less space. Also, if you need to `rename` this subject in your case you will need to perform updates over many rows - in my way, you will update only the name in the `SubjectTable` - one row.

Comment: I understand your point on the second scenario clearly. What about the first case like student_id,subject1,subject2,subject3 as column names and (1,80,80,80) as one row where student_id is foreign key?

Comment: It's bad because each subject is a column. If you need to add or delete subject, you are going to perform DML operation - drop/add column which might be slow. If you are using separate table in order to add new subject you will simply insert new row - which is of course fast as hell. Check also this - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Satisfying_1NF

Answer (score 0):

I think you're going to need 3 tables:

- `students`
- `subjects`
- `scores`

`students` and `subjects` are master tables. They're going to provide `student_id` and `subject_id` for `scores` table as composite key.  [Here's the relational database design.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wzLDC.png)

The point of seperating them into 3 tables is to avoid *data anomalies*. There are 3 anomalies:

1. Insert anomaly
2. Delete anomaly
3. Update anomaly

To learn more about data anomalies: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/anomalies-in-relational-model/